# Spring OAuth2 login with authorization_code and without redirect

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I am fetching the `authorization_code` for an oauth2 login in my frontend via this code:

```
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      client_id: 'my-client-id',
      scope: 'email profile',
      redirect_uri: 'postmessage',
      ux_mode: 'popup',
      callback: (response) => {
        console.log(response)
        // possible?
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google?code=" + response.code)
      },
    });
```

The [response](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference) contains the `authorization_code` which should be sent to my Spring Boot backend, be validated and in the success case, a JWT will be sent back to the frontend.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .oauth2login()
        .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                DefaultOAuth2User defaultOAuth2User = (DefaultOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();
                // get JWT token, etc

                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().write(/* ... */);
                httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush();
            }
        })
}
```

Do I need to create a custom endpoint for that or can I use the built-in functionality (calling e.g. `/login/oauth2/code/google?code=...`) and then validate it? Would it be possible with `.tokenEndpoint().accessTokenResponseClient()`?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this. Most of the spring boot based tutorials talk about using redirect authentication mechanism, whereas I prefer not being redirected between pages for login.